# Including resources in "non-installed" class

Tags: document-classes, input, texmf

I am trying to modify an existing class to simplify its usage. Basically I would just like the user to copy a folder which contains the `.cls` file and some resources (a png file with a logo, some fonts and a text file with some information to be read by the `.cls` file).

My problem is that I cannot make the `.cls` file find the files. For e.g. I am using `\InputIfFileExists{./<nameoftextfile>}{}{\ClassError...}` but that does not work (it always throws out the error).

Is there a way to refer to a file in the same folder as the `.cls` file?

Btw, if I were to "install" the class file in the `texmf-local` folder, how would I refer to the resources (which I would then put in some subfolders of texmf-local)? It does not seem reasonable to hard code the path to the texmf-folder in the `.cls` file.

Comment: Where is the working directory? Is the `.tex` file being compiled in the directory with the `.cls` file? If not, you need to install the `.cls` file as it should be in the search path i.e. either in the working directory, with the document, or in TEXMFHOME or TEXMFLOCAL. In the latter cases, it doesn't matter if the resources etc. are in a sub-directory, because they'll be found anyway so long as they are in the search path.

Comment: Never say `the error` if you are asking for help. How should we know which error is `the error`? Copy-paste the text of the error message into your post instead.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I mean the error of the InputIfFileExists is thrown. I believe I can define the text of this error to whatever I want so it is not helpful (in my case I have defined it to be "File <filename> not found").

Answer (score 2):

Normally reffering to another file in the same directory like you did should perfectly work. However, it is alredy sufficent to say `\InputIfFileExists{<nameoftextfile>}{}{\ClassError...}`. (But: `<nameoftextfile>` won't be enough. The extension must be there!) To refer to a directory one level above also in TeX you would use `../<dir>`. The following setup should achieve what you are looking for.

### Directory setup

```
texmf-local
 |
 +-- dir myclass
 |  |
 |  +-- file myclass.cls
 |  +-- file myexternalfile.tex
 |
 +-- dir resources
 |  |  
 |  +-- file resource.tex
```

### Files

#### `main.tex`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2017/01/22 Example LaTeX class]
\LoadClass{article}
\InputIfFileExists{myexternalfile.tex}{}{\ClassError{myclass}{file not found}{}}
\InputIfFileExists{../resources/resource.tex}{}{\ClassError{myclass}{file not found}{}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{} \myothermacro
\end{document}
```

#### `myexternalfile.tex`

```
\def\mymacro{hello}
```

#### `resource.tex`

```
\def\myothermacro{world}
```

Comment: You are making a crucial implicit assumption: that the document being compiled is in the directory with the class file.

Comment: @cfr -- darn! you're right. did you check if it fails? I guess so, but i'd be interested if you have a little time.

Comment: What do you mean? I meant: of course it will fail if the directory with the class is not the working directory (and the class is not installed). I figured you assumed that it was the working directory. So now I'm confused. Do you mean it fails anyway?

Comment: I mean: `\documentclass{<filename>}` shouldn't give a path, as far as I know, and it can't possibly work without one if the directory is not the working one.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a directory with a bunch of files. One is the `.cls` file and the others are things to be read by the `.cls` file.

The user, presumably, has a `.tex` document which calls your class

```
\documentclass{fabulousclass}
...
```

The easiest way for users to use your class is to put the `.tex` document into the directory with everything else.

Your class can just say,

```
\input{extensionfile}% extensionfile.tex
\input{configfile.cfg}% configfile.cfg
\includegraphics{logo}% logo.png
```

Then everything will be found.

If you do not want users to have to make your directory their working directory, you need to tell them to install the files.

The details depend on your TeX distribution. For TeX Live, there are two main options:

1. `TEXMFHOME`
2. `TEXMFLOCAL`

The first option is the most straightforward. Users simply make a directory in their personal TEXMF tree. On a Unix-ish system:

```bash
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex
# where fabulousclassdirectoryname is the name of the directory containing your class and resources
mv -n fabulousclassdirectoryname $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/
```

Then the files will be found regardless of working directory.

The procedure is the same for `TEXMFLOCAL` with an additional step. This process will normally require privileges on Unix-ish systems, at least.

```bash
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex
# where fabulousclassdirectoryname is the name of the directory containing your class and resources
mv -n fabulousclassdirectoryname $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/
mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
```

That's all.

You can put the resources in a different sub-directory of `TEXMFLOCAL` or `TEXMFHOME` if you wish. But I don't see why you'd want to do that and it will just confuse people.